# Applying transformation rule for corresponding indices?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, map, rule

I have two lists, that looks like below

```
list1 = {a, x, b, x, x, c};
list2 = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

Any time there is an `x` in the first list (`list1`), I want to replace it with the corresponding element in the second list (`list2`).

**Any suggestions on nice ways to go about doing this?**

---

I realize this should be simple with a loop (get the length of the lists, let the loop iterator be the index, and just compare and replace element by element)

However, I believe its usually better to use `Map`, `MapThread`, or take advantage of `Listable` attributes. I don't see how I can do so here, but feel there might be a simple way?

Perhaps something with `MapIndexed` as mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109496/39270)

---

Edit: The best way I can come up with is below. It still requires using a local environment `Module` though, which I feel like might be avoided by a better approach.

```
Module[{rules, keys},
 keys = Flatten@Position[{a, x, b, x, x, c}, x];
 rules = AssociationThread[keys -> {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}[[keys]]];
 ReplacePart[{a, x, b, x, x, c}, rules]
 ]
```

Edit 2:
I have realized my question is perhaps a duplicate of [this old question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9784/39270), but answers have just been posted here so I will not delete my question. Sorry for the confusion and mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MapIndexed[If[# === x, list2[[#2[[1]]]], #] &, list1]
```

> ```
>  {a, 3, b, 5, 6, c}
> ```

Alternatively,

```
xpos = Flatten @ Position[list1, x];
res = list1; res[[xpos]] = list2[[xpos]];  res
```

> ```
>  {a, 3, b, 5, 6, c}
> ```

and

```
(Transpose[{list1, list2}] /. {x, i_} :> {i, i})[[All, 1]]
```

> ```
> {a, 3, b, 5, 6, c}
> ```

and alternative way to use `ReplacePart`:

```
xpos = Flatten @ Position[list1, x];
ReplacePart[list1, Thread[xpos -> list2[[xpos]]]]
```

> ```
> {a, 3, b, 5, 6, c}
> ```

Comment: I like the first one since it does not require defining a new (possibly local) variable. The reason you have `#2[[1]]` though, is because I think `MapIndexed` uses the index in brackets as the second argument, yes? (i.e. it uses `{i}` instead of `i`). I see you have also edited to add more solutions, some of which also may not need local variables. Thank you.

Comment: @user106860, you are right; the argument  #2  refers to a list in `MapIndexed`.

Answer (score 4):

```
list1 = {a, x, b, x, x, c};
list2 = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

Find the positions of the first list

```
ix = Position[list1, x]
(* {{2}, {4}, {5}} *)
```

Replace them in the second list

```
ReplacePart[list1, Thread[ix -> Extract[list2, ix]]]
(* {a, 3, b, 5, 6, c} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = {a, x, b, x, x, c};
list2 = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

---

Using `SubsetMap`:

```
p = Position[list1, x];

vals = Extract[list2, p];

SubsetMap[vals &, list1, p]

(*{a, 3, b, 5, 6, c}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MapThread[If[#1 === x, #2, #1]&, {list1, list2}]
```

{a, 3, b, 5, 6, c}